# Alternative for javascript window method for visualforce pages in lightning

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, locker-service

With the lightning readiness report there is mention that javascript window method won't perform as supposed to in Lightning. Salesforce documentation suggest sforce.one navigation methods to replace certain methods such as

> window.location()

. 
My question is, what are the alternative in terms of

> window.close()

.

> window.open()

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I came with the same problem. I did not find the correct syntax supported in Lightning.I moved to Lightning Component or going to use style to create popup in VF page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you'd use a modal instead of close/open. See the [lightning:overlayLibrary](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:overlayLibrary/documentation) component for methods you can use to display and close a modal.

Comment: Yeah I tought so. Do I have to describe the behaviour of my modal in the controller ?

Comment: @nyambalakesu You just create a component, and hand the overlay library the component and some optional parameters, it takes care of the rest.

Comment: But how would Visualforce leverage a Lightning modal?

Comment: @CharlesT Locker Service does not restrict Visualforce, so you'd still use open/close/etc.

Comment: Sorry let me clarify. I believe Overlay Library component communicates with the one.app container in Lightning Experience in order to open modals. But Lightning components embedded in the Visualforce iFrame don't have access to the one.app container. So how would Visualforce be able to leverage that library?

Comment: @CharlesT For those situations, open/close can still be used.It's just that when you're in an app (LEX, communities, Salesforce App), you're expected not to use these.

Comment: @sfdcfox This still doesn't address my dispute with your answer. The original question was about Visualforce. Your answer pointed to a library that cannot be used in Visualforce. So I don't understand why you put that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Great answer [sfdcfox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2984/sfdcfox), using modals is definitively the better way to go!

In addition, for some cases, the `window` methods can be still useful:

- `window.open()` and `window.location()` display a confirmation dialog to ask the user if they would like to navigate away from the current domain. This is in an effort to prevent phishing attacks, e.g. salesforce.com -> saelsforce.com.
- `window.close()` should work as expected, just remember that scripts may not close windows that were not opened by them.

I hope this helps!